# Stepping on Grass (displacing/rotating grass by object in geometry nodes)?

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement, instances

I would like to have Grass be "flattened" by an Object by using Geometry Nodes.
So when a foot steps on the grass, it will be rotated aside.
[image]

I managed to make the grass face the Object but not away from it :D
[image]

Also, just the closest Grass blades should be rotated away.
Any ideas, how to do that?

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you don't want grass fully recovers after step, I suggest using dynamic paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to work with the node *Geometry Proximity* and create a direction vector from both resulting positions. With this you get the cross product which serves as axis for a new rotation.

Something like this:

[image]

This would make the objects point away from your sphere within a certain radius.

[image]

You can change the intensity of the rotation and the radius of effect in this example with the mapping node marked in green:

[image]

The Node Group at a glance:

[image]

[image]